# R: How to change values in all of the rows that come after a specific row in a group?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I am trying to calculate average concentrations of air pollution per ID. The issue is that some IDs require 3 separate averages per ID due to time lags. Example data (where time difference is the difference between the datetime and lag(datetime); when time_difference is greater than 600, that indicates a new average needs to be calculated beginning at that time; the start of a new ID automatically has time_difference=0):

df1:

| **ID** | **DateTime** | **Time_difference** | **Threshold** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:01 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:02 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:03 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:04 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:05 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:01 | 2096 | 1 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:02 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:03 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:04 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:05 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:01 | 3896 | 2 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:02 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:03 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:04 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:05 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-10-13 00:10:06 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-10-13 00:10:07 | 1 | 0 |

.... etc

All of these rows have a corresponding concentration level, but right now that is irrelevant. What I am trying to do is create a new column labeled "group" where I can have all of the values associated with the ID that are before the row where threshold==1 to be "group 1" and all the values associated with the same ID that are when threshold==1 until threshold==2 to be "group 2" and all the values with the same ID that are when threshold==2 until the next ID to be "group 3":

| **ID** | **DateTime** | **Time_difference** | **Threshold** | **group** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:01 | 0 | 0 | group 1 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:02 | 1 | 0 | group 1 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:03 | 1 | 0 | group 1 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:04 | 1 | 0 | group 1 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 22:30:05 | 1 | 0 | group 1 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:01 | 2096 | 1 | group 2 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:02 | 1 | 0 | group 2 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:03 | 1 | 0 | group 2 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:04 | 1 | 0 | group 2 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 23:05:05 | 1 | 0 | group 2 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:01 | 3896 | 2 | group 3 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:02 | 1 | 0 | group 3 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:03 | 1 | 0 | group 3 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:04 | 1 | 0 | group 3 |
| 0 | 2022-10-13 00:10:05 | 1 | 0 | group 3 |
| 1 | 2022-10-13 00:10:06 | 0 | 0 | group 1 |
| 1 | 2022-10-13 00:10:07 | 1 | 0 | group 1 |

.... etc

The idea would then be the group by the ID and the group and calculate the averages concentrations.

I've been able to do this when there are just 2 groups per ID, but when there are 3 groups I cannot adapt the code. This is how I created the two groups (very inefficiently, I know):

```
temp <- df1 %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(threshold==1) %>% 
    mutate(thresh_time = DateTime) %>%
    dplyr::select(ID, thresh_time)

df2 <- left_join(df1, temp, by="ID", all.x=TRUE)

df3 <- df2 %>%
    mutate(group = ifelse(DateTime<thresh_time | ID!=lag(ID), "group 1", "group 2"))
```

So for this solution I had to create yet another variable, being the thresh_time or the DateTime when threshold==1, and then assign that time to all of the values for a specific ID, and then create the groups based on whether or not the DateTime of that row is greater than or less than the thresh_time. This only works for two groups, though, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to adapt it to 3 groups, if that is even possible.

The final dataset would ideally look something like this:

| **ID** | **group** | **Concentration** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | group 1 | 55890 |
| 0 | group 2 | 67491 |
| 0 | group 3 | 87645 |
| 1 | group 1 | 94827 |
| 1 | group 2 | 61527 |
| 2 | group 1 | 45362 |

Any ideas on how to get here? I have been at this for weeks...

Comment: Could use something simple such as `mutate(df, Group = cumsum(Threshold > 0) + 1, .by = ID)`? (For `.by` argument using `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0...)

Answer (score 0):

One way to create a group with your specification is by assigning `group 1` to all rows of the `group` column, and then edit the group number by using `for` loop:

```
fgroup <- function(dat){
     dat$group <- "group 1"
     n <- 1
     for(k in 1:nrow(dat)) {
              if(dat$Threshold[k] > 0) {
                      n = n + 1
                      dat$group[k:nrow(dat)] <- paste("group", n)
              }
         } 
     return(dat)
 }
```

Then, split the data frame based on `ID`, and run the function to each ID, and then combine the result.

```
dat2 <- split(dat, dat$ID) |> map(fgroup) |> bind_rows()
dat2

   ID             DateTime Time_difference Threshold   group
1   0 2022-10-13 22:30:01                0         0 group 1
2   0 2022-10-13 22:30:02                1         0 group 1
3   0 2022-10-13 22:30:03                1         0 group 1
4   0 2022-10-13 22:30:04                1         0 group 1
5   0 2022-10-13 22:30:05                1         0 group 1
6   0 2022-10-13 23:05:01             2096         1 group 2
7   0 2022-10-13 23:05:02                1         0 group 2
8   0 2022-10-13 23:05:03                1         0 group 2
9   0 2022-10-13 23:05:04                1         0 group 2
10  0 2022-10-13 23:05:05                1         0 group 2
11  0 2022-10-13 00:10:01             3896         2 group 3
12  0 2022-10-13 00:10:02                1         0 group 3
13  0 2022-10-13 00:10:03                1         0 group 3
14  0 2022-10-13 00:10:04                1         0 group 3
15  0 2022-10-13 00:10:05                1         0 group 3
16  1 2022-10-13 00:10:06                0         0 group 1
17  1 2022-10-13 00:10:07                1         0 group 1
```

Then, you can calculate the concentration mean of each group for each ID:

```
dat2 |> group_by(ID, group) |> summarise(mean(Concentration))
```